# Getting international fundamental stock market data

Tags: market-data, historical-data, fundamentals

I am thinking of building some custom stock screening tool.

For this I need fundamental data (parts of balance sheet, earnings statements, cash flow statement if available, probably some minimal stock market quotes, ...) for lots of companies in several countries, not just the US. Real-time data is not needed, it can be significantly delayed if that makes it easier or cheaper.

What are my options for this?
Where can I find this data?
Would it be more efficient to collect this data from various websites and starting to build a database using someone from upwork, or to buy this data service somewhere at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quandl has two premium fundamental datasets that may be of interest to you, [Robur Global Select Stock Fundamentals](https://www.quandl.com/data/RB1-Robur-Global-Select-Stock-Fundamentals/documentation/introduction) and [Mergent Global Fundamentals Data](https://www.quandl.com/databases/MF1/documentation/introduction). Quandl also has [fundamental datasets](https://www.quandl.com/search?query=fundamental) for specific countries including the US, China, and India.

If you have an Interactive Brokers account and can program against their API, you can sign up for [Reuters Worldwide Fundamentals](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/reuters_fundamentals.html#report_type&gsc.tab=0) and build your own database. This dataset has good global coverage and is very cheap (only a few dollars per month for non-professionals), but it will be significantly more development work to build your own database using IB's API, as opposed to purchasing a ready-made database from Quandl.